# Java server not connecting

Tags: java

Given the following Java Code:

```
public Server() throws IOException {
    socket = new ServerSocket(2000);
    System.out.println("Opening server at port: " + socket.getLocalPort());
    System.out.println("IP: " + socket.getInetAddress());
    tab = new SpookerTab();
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");
                    Socket client = socket.accept();
                    System.out.println(client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " has connected.");
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new SpookerClient(client));
                    threads.put(client, thread);
                    thread.start();
                    System.out.println("Client found!");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

It never passes `socket.accept()`.

Why is this?

```
Java Server java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: I assume you have another process attempting to connect to it?

Comment: You need another thread/process to connect to it for accept() to return. Connection timed out suggests you have a firewall blocking this port.

Comment: The server connects never - it is waiting for incoming connections. Hence you need a client that connects to TCP port 2000 (your server) as Joe C already pointed out.

Comment: The exception the OP reports can only be thrown from a client; but we don't have the code to that client. Most likely, there's a firewall in the way, but we can't tell without the client code.

Answer (score 0):

> *It never passes socket.accept().*
>
> *Why is this?*

But this is how the server should work

```
Socket client = socket.accept();
```

will block the thread WAITING for a client to connect...

the javadoc states:

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The
>   method blocks until a connection is made.
>
> A new Socket s is created and, if there is a security manager, the
>   security manager's checkAccept method is called with
>   s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() and s.getPort() as its arguments
>   to ensure the operation is allowed. This could result in a
>   SecurityException.

if no client is connecting to the server, then the execution is no going forward..